# Spring Web Flow: Call bean's method as target action

Tags: java, jsf, spring-webflow

I have a `JSF`+`Spring Web Flow` application and I'd like to move from one view to another one using a method defined in the view's bean.

So, my flow.xml is like the following:

```
<flow ...>
     <var name="myBean" class="mypackage.myclass" />
     <view-state id="list">
         <transition on="myEvent" to="#{myBean.onMyEvent()}"
     </view-state>
</flow>
```

In the bean I've defined:

```
public String onMyEvent(final SelectEvent event) {
    //Do something
    return "input";
}
```

The button is simply:

```
<h:commandButton id="myButton" action="myEvent" ajax="false" value="myButton" />
```

When I push on the button that contains the `action="myEvent"` I get the error:

> EL1004E: Method call: Method onMyEvent() cannot be found on type [...]

So, what's wrong with my code? How can I call a method in my bean on some event?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the  method signature in the error and the one in your code. Notice a difference?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes but the action should be the one specified in the `flow.xml`. So I believe that's right, isn't?

Comment: No idea, I don't use complex setups like this. JSF has its own 'flows' which do not require relatively complex solutions like these. But your solution is exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved using the [org.springframework.webflow.engine.RequestControlContext](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/api/org/springframework/webflow/engine/RequestControlContext.html) that can handle event manually like in the following example:

Front-end side (call to the bean's method):

```
<h:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{myBean.onMyEvent}" />
```

Bean (forward to the Spring Web Flow handler):

```
public void onMyEvent(final SelectEvent event) {
    // Fill the bean for next view
    final RequestContext requestContext = RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    requestContext.getFlowScope().put("nextBean", nextBean);
    final RequestControlContext rec = (RequestControlContext) requestContext;
    rec.handleEvent(new Event(this, "myEvent")); // the action managed by Spring Web Flow
}
```

And finally in the `flow.xml` (manage the transition to the next view)

```
<view-state id="myView">
    <transition on="myEvent" to="nextView" />
</view-state>
```